# Github Pages Error Message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, npm, github-pages

I have some questions about gh-pages. I have a githab repository and project
Page as githubpages. In the project directory that I use the
Github repository created has git push, git pull, git build and
git deploy without problems. The site can be found at http://ux.example.com
call. Unfortunately, it is not possible to make the page using https://ux.example.com
call. In the settings, it is explicitly pointed out,
That it is not possible to call custom subdomains with https.

I have on another computer the repository via git clone
downloaded. Git pull, git push, git build works perfectly.

I suspect that the cause is the subdomain. How do I solve the problem?

With git deploy I get the following error message:

```
yarn run deploy
yarn run v0.27.5
$ gh-pages -d styleguide
fatal: attempt to fetch/clone from a shallow repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```